# Laravel way to add a column value on all models like created_at

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model, traits

I need to add a column to some of my database tables and populate that on `Model::create()`.

All I want is functionality like Laravel built in `timestamps` i.e `created_at` and `updated_at`

I know of some solutions but I wanted to know if something else could be done in such case.
For example:

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::created(function ($user) {
        //
    });
}
```

OR

```
class UserObserver
{
    public function creating(User $user)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

I will need to do that for every model which is repeating myself.

Another solution that comes to my mind is creating a `BaseModel` and then extend everything from that.

---

I wanted to do something like we have in `SoftDeletes` trait, Add whatever logic inside of that and populate that column using some laravel hook that I am not aware of. If someone can guide me to accomplish such thing using traits and HOW?

Answer (score 2):

You can extend all your models off of a base model class (a small refactor), and then in that class add a booted method with your custom logic.

If you then need (or already have) extra logic in a model (say the user model) that uses the booted method, you can still keep that, but make sure you call parent::booted();

```
class BaseModel extends Model {
    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::created(function ($model) {
            //logic
        });
    }
}
```

```
class User extends BaseModel {
    protected static function booted()
    {
        parent::booted();
        //any other logic you may have/want in user
    }
}
```

This is in my opinion the most scalable approach. Make use of OOP! You can also then reuse this base class for other global logic in the future.

Comment: I knew this and have mentioned this in my question. I wanted some approach using traits, so I dont have to change all my models.

Comment: Adding a trait to all your models would be the same amount of work and essentially the same logic, you can do just the same with a trait though just override the booted method in your trait and optionally call a new static method with a different in that trait if you want extra custom logic